# What are we doing with questions asking about services?

Tags: discussion, questions, topic

> - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6791/87
> - [Is Ethtrade.org real deal or a scam?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3844/87)

I think it's pretty obvious they are either offtopic promoting services or generating unwanted, opinionated content.

However, what is your opinion on how to deal with such questions in the future?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to live in public, you have to deal with people who have less knowledge than you, because they have been exploring a certain topic for a shorter time and not so much in-depth as you.

This is a question and answer site; people post questions about topics they want to learn, other people answer. Some of these questions will touch the parts of the Ethereum ecosystem which you don't like or don't respect.

**The way to deal with such questions is to answer them; with factual, informative answers.**

By hiding otherwise easily accessible information or trying to forbid such questions, instead of addressing them, **you make** the information **goldminer.io** provides (clear, nice, appealing to non-technical audience) **stand out**.

---

As I am the author of one of the posts I think your reaction is very un-StackExchange-ish. To my question you:

- edited the links out
- issued a personal warning: "*Be careful!*"
- called the question: "*either offtopic promoting services or generating unwanted, opinionated content*"

Did you read and understood the question at all? I asked:

- what is that service (I don't know if it's a pool, or what? I don't know the Ethereum ecosystem yet, struggling with basic terminologyーhow can I gain that knowledge?)
- how can I as a beginner evaluate its trustworthiness (for the very reasons I specified, it's closed-source, it's shiny and non-technicalーwhere can I get information?)

How come these questions *promote the service* or *generate unwanted, opinionated content*?

<sup>Well, in fact it generated unwanted and opinionated response of yours, but that's another story.</sup>

Does a link in a question on SE promote the service? There's no juice, Google does not consider these links for positioning.

From your response I understand you consider the service fishy and you don't like it, however your reaction effectively makes a favour to that service.

People don't like when you warn them "Be careful!" for the fact that they wanted to learn something from you. I understand it comes from the fact that you care, but if you act arrogantly, others will happily turn to GoldMiner for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be closed with this following reason from stackoverflow:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, [describe the
>   problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has
>   been done so far to solve it.

[More info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134)

BTW, this is how the first question in the OP was handled.